# How can I record sound, replay, and save it?

Tags: windows, software-rec, audio-recording

I'm hunting for an application. It should have three functions which are to record my voice, replay what it records, and save the voice into a file.

No more extra functions are needed.

Note, saving should not be required before I replay the record.

The length of my voice won't exceed 2 mins. File type is not a concern. MP3, wav, ect are all acceptable.

Comment: What operating system? If Windows, then check out the built-in Sound Recorder.

Comment: ...and on Linux, GNOME Sound Recorder.

Comment: Sorry for I did not memtion the operating system. It should be Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is your best bet besides some of the built-in, very basic recording programs on Windows/Mac/Linux. It does everything you've listed and can save to a variety of files (mp3, etc).